# Why is redux's combine reducer complaining about method overload when using typescript and react-redux-firebase?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

**The problem**

I have a basic project with just a minimal boilerplate, because I wanted to try out `react-redux-firebase`. So I set everything up according to the typescript example from here: https://github.com/prescottprue/react-redux-firebase/tree/master/examples/complete/typescript

But this part:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers<RootState>({
  firebase: firebaseReducer,
  firestore: firestoreReducer
});
```

Is complaining:

```
> firestore: Reducer<FirestoreReducer.Reducer, any> No overload matches
> this call. Overload 1 of 3,
```

I made a minimal codesandbox demo to reproduce the problem:

https://codesandbox.io/s/great-perlman-p6g7p?file=/src/store/index.ts

You can see the error on line `54` altough the app is running just fine. On my local client it won't render, I just see the error in the browser (overload...).

What am I doing wrong here? It has to be something about typescript, I'm a real beginner when it comes to typescript.